# Symfony2 - Admin's authorization by any user

Tags: php, symfony

We have users who send feedbacks with errors and bugs on the site. Some bugs can be seen only being on user account. Is there a possibility on Symfony/FOS to realize a authorization by any user? Of course, this can be done only by user with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN. 

I see it something like that:

```
public function authAction()
{
    $usermanager = $this->container->get('userManager');
    /** @var Entity/User $user */
    $user = $usermanager->findSomeUser();
    if ($currentUserIsGranted) {

        /** do authorization */

        return new RedirectResponse('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but the Symfony2 security layer embraces an "impersonating" functionality that allows you to temporarily switch to a different user.

Have a look at this one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

Answer (score 0):

You must to secure action like

```
public function authAction()
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

}
```

You can read more in [How to secure any Service or Method in your Application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html)